# WordPress: Deregister script that lacks handle?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I'm using a plugin (Mobile.nav) that doesn't assign a handle to a script that it loads. It loads the webfont.js script through JS.

How can I deregister a script that lacks a handle?

```
WebFontConfig = {
    google: { families: [ 'Open+Sans::latin' ] }
  };
  (function() {
    var wf = document.createElement('script');
    wf.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https' : 'http') +
      '://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/webfont/1/webfont.js';
    wf.type = 'text/javascript';
    wf.async = 'true';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(wf, s);
  })();
```

Comment: It isn't registered at all, so it can't be deregistered. If the plugin is so poorly designed that it doesn't use the WP script functions, I would just fork it and modify the code directly.

Comment: Where is the js that loads the file queued? Could you deregister that script?